# I am trying to install four exe's one after another using batch file

Tags: batch-file

witha batch file i am trying to install four exe's exe1.exe,exe2.exe,exe3.exe and exe4.exe i used the following commands to install them

```
@echo  off
echo %time%
timeout 1

start /wait /b "C\Softwares\exe1.exe" /t |more
start /wait /b "C\Softwares\exe2.exe" /t |more
start /wait /b "C\Softwares\exe3.exe" /t |more
start /wait /b "C\Softwares\exe4.exe" /t |more

echo %time%
```

with the above script i am achieving the task but all the setup wizards of 4 exe's opening at a time. I want to open exe2.exe setup wizard after the installation completion of exe1.exe and same for remaining exe's also.

need help with this issue awaiting reply from anyone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your title says two files but then you are talking about four... Anyway, your executables are no console applications, which is the problem here, I think...

Comment: I think you should probably search for some condition that gets fulfilled once the installation gets completed: a file/folder that gets created only when installation is complete, a register that proves it is installed  correctly, check if the program it installs is in the list of installed software,... . Once you've found that condition you can poll it and let the nxt exe start only when that condition is met. Reading the help messages of the installers (if available) or documentation of your exe's could help you find these conditions I think. It's the only advice I can give unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, can you please give me an example @J.Baoby

Comment: @PavanChowdary see my example posted as an answer (had no choice, was too big). Hope it helps ;)

Comment: @J.Baoby thank you. i will try that and let you know.

Comment: @J.Baoby I tried the answer you given below. it is working now thank you very much

Comment: Perfect!  :-) Great to hear that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not an attempt to an answer. This is as answer to [the comment of the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459526/i-am-trying-to-install-four-exes-one-after-another-using-batch-file?noredirect=1#comment74000325_43459526) who asked further clarification. Parts explained in here may lead to an answer though.*

So what I meant is basically this:

```
start /wait /b "C\Softwares\exe1.exe" /t |more
< WAIT HERE ON CONDITION FOR exe1 >

start /wait /b "C\Softwares\exe2.exe" /t |more
< WAIT HERE ON CONDITION FOR exe2 >

start /wait /b "C\Softwares\exe3.exe" /t |more
< WAIT HERE ON CONDITION FOR exe3 >

start /wait /b "C\Softwares\exe4.exe" /t |more
```

Where each `< WAIT HERE ON CONDITION FOR exeN>` has to be replaced with some kind of loop that keeps verifying a proof that the installation for exeN succeeded (or failed?). That proof can then be turned into a condition in batch using an [`IF`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) statement and the looping can be done using a `goto`.

```
:WaitLoopExeN
IF NOT <condition_exe_N> (
    REM Use a timeout to wait before verifying again, else it may take too much resources
    timeout 5 > nul
    goto :WaitLoopExeN
)
```

As you may see if you follow the `IF`-link, the number of conditions you can verify with an [`IF`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) statement are pretty limited. But besides the basic conditions for an if-statement in batch (variable comparison and file existence), if you can find a command that verifies your condition/proof and sets its exit code and the error level correctly (in most cases both are the same), you can at least be sure you can turn it into an `IF` statement with the `IF ERRORLEVEL` construct.

As an exemple, let us consider that your `exe1.exe` installer creates a registry `EXEC_DIRECTORY` in the key `ROOT\SOME\KEY\FOR\EXE1` when installation is completed. The existence of the registry will be your proof and the condition will be "if registry exists". Unfortunately, there is no batch `IF` statement I know of that verifies that directly. But there exists a command to query a registry: [`REG QUERY`](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html). So the following should be able to replace the `< WAIT HERE ON CONDITION FOR exe1 >`:

```
:WaitLoopExe1
REM Query the registry, will set errorlevel on 1 or greater if it didn't succeed
REG QUERY ROOT\SOME\KEY\FOR\EXE1 /v EXEC_DIRECTORY > nul
REM Now verify errorlevel
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    timeout 5 > nul
    goto :WaitLoopExe1
)
```

If on the other hand the existence of file/directory is the proof of the success of the installation of exe1.exe it would have been:

```
:WaitLoopExe1
REM Verify if file exists, if not enter inside the parenthesis
IF NOT EXIST "path\to\file\that\proofs\success" (
    timeout 5 > nul
    goto :WaitLoopExe1
)
```

I hope this helps.
Good luck